# What is .freeze() in Kotlin/Native?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-native

I see yet another function in Kotlin/Native, that does not exist in the Kotlin JVM or JS. What does it?

Comment: Looks like a native function from a search in the source code, related to memory management? Not sure, but it looks like it

Answer (score 8):

From [Kotlin native's Concurrency docs](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-native/blob/master/CONCURRENCY.md#object-transfer-and-freezing)

> Freezing is a runtime operation making given object subgraph immutable, by modifying the object header so that future mutation attempts lead to throwing an InvalidMutabilityException. It is deep, so if an object has a pointer to another objects - transitive closure of such objects will be frozen. Freezing is the one way transformation, frozen objects cannot be unfrozen. Frozen objects have a nice property that due to their immutability, they can be freely shared between multiple workers/threads not breaking the "mutable XOR shared" invariant.

Answer (score 2):

Sharing a more recent and easier explanation from Kotlin Multiplatform Mobile docs [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/mobile/concurrency-overview.html#immutable-and-frozen-state):

> The Native runtime adds an extension function freeze() to all classes.
> Calling freeze() will freeze an object, and everything referenced by
> the object, recursively.
> Eg:

```
data class MoreData(val strData: String, var width: Float)
data class SomeData(val moreData: MoreData, var count: Int)
//...
val sd = SomeData(MoreData("abc", 10.0), 0)
sd.freeze()
```

[image]

> - freeze() is a one-way operation. You can't unfreeze something.
> - freeze() is not available in shared Kotlin code, but several libraries
>   provide expect and actual declarations for using it in shared code.
>   However, if you're using a concurrency library, like
>   kotlinx.coroutines, it will likely freeze data that crosses thread
>   boundaries automatically.
> - freeze is not unique to Kotlin. You can also
>   find it in Ruby and JavaScript.